# Regex backreferencing for month, day, and year?

Tags: c#, regex

I am using a regex statement to match a date in a filename. I would like to break the output into groups (Which my statement does).

I have tested the output so far but I cannot seem to get my group values to pass to a string so that I can create directories with them. Matter of fact I cant seem to get my group values at all.

I understand that this could be done without regex but I opted to go this way to try and learn it. My input string is a filename `"Result5_14_20009 1_30_00 PM.xml"`

How can I create a string `"month"` where I pass the value to group 1, etc.?

Here is what I have so far:

```
private void btnSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = "Result*.xml";
    string sourcePath = txtSource.Text;
    string targetPath = txtDest.Text;

    //Get Data from Filename
    string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);
    Regex date = new Regex(@"([1-9]|[0-2])_(\d{2})_(\d{4})", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

    foreach (string s in files)
    {
        Match m = date.Match(s);
        if (m.Success)
        {
            //Pass Groups to String

            //Create Dir for Group 3 (Year) 
            //Create Dir for Group 1 (Month)
            //Create Dir for Group 2 (Day)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `Groups` property off of your `Match` object. To continue your example:

```
if (m.Success)
{
    //groups[0] will be the entire filename
    string year = m.Groups[3].Value;
    string month = m.Groups[1].Value;
    string day = m.Groups[2].Value;

    //create dirs...
}
```

A site I have gone to time and again for testing .NET regex behavior is this one: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx, it shows you what groups you will get given your sample input and regex.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the groups through the [Match.Groups Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups.aspx) and the group values through the [Group.Value Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.value.aspx). To combine the group values into a path, you can use the [Path.Combine Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx). Ant to create the directory, you can use the [Directory.CreateDirectory Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx):

```
string path = Path.Combine(
  @"C:\Users\...\Foo", m.Groups[3].Value, m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value);

// path == @"C:\Users\...\Foo\2000\5\14"

Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

Comment: why do I get a "string does not contain a definition" error in vs.

Comment: according to what I just read argument 1 for path.combine method must be an absolute path. In this case I have a folder browser dialogue to select or create the root. Any ideas on how I can still use this method.

Comment: string path = Path.Combine([myFolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.selectedpath.aspx), m.Groups[3].Value, m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value);

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, you just need to defined your groups within the regex expression:

```
Regex date = new Regex(@"(?<MONTH>[1-9]|[0-2])_(?<DAY>\d{2})_(?<YEAR>\d{4})", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

foreach(Match oMatch in oMatchCollection) 
{ 

 Console.WriteLine("MONTH: "+oMatch.Groups["MONTH"].Value);
 Console.WriteLine("DAY: "+oMatch.Groups["DAY"].Value); 
 Console.WriteLine("YEAR: "+oMatch.Groups["YEAR"].Value); 
}
```

Comment: that explains my brick wall. Thanks.

Comment: Full example helped my unrelated question! Thnx

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this. I'm renaming the files as well because I like my file names to collate properly.

```
static void OrganizeFiles( DirectoryInfo src , DirectoryInfo tgt )
{
  foreach ( FileInfo file in src.EnumerateFiles("result*.xml") )
  {
    Match m = FileNamePatternRegex.Match( file.Name ) ;
    bool processed = false ;
    if ( m.Success)
    {
      string datetime = m.Groups["datetime"].Value ;
      DateTime resultDate ;
      bool parseSucceeded = DateTime.TryParseExact( datetime , "M_d_yyyy h_m_s tt" , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture , DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces , out resultDate ) ;
      if ( parseSucceeded )
      {
        DirectoryInfo subDir = tgt.CreateSubdirectory( resultDate.ToString(  @"yyyy\MM\dd" ) ) ;
        string newName     = resultDate.ToString( "result.yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.xml" ) ;
        string destination = Path.Combine( subDir.FullName , newName ) ;
        file.MoveTo( destination ) ;
        processed = true ;
      }
    }
    if ( !processed )
    {
      Console.WriteLine( "skipping file {0}" , file.FullName ) ;
    }
  }
  return ;
}
const string          FileNamePattern      = @"^result(?<datetime>\d+_\d+_\d+ +\d+_\d+_\d+ +(am|pm))\.xml" ;
static readonly Regex FileNamePatternRegex = new Regex( FileNamePattern , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture ) ;
```